# Comparación de un string y un 0 (Duda)

Tags: php, php7

tengo una duda. quiero compartir mi caso aunque ya lo solucione.

mi codigo es por ejemplo el siguiente.

```
$data="Hola Mundo";
if($data == 0){
  echo "Válido";
}
```

mi pensado era validar contra 0 como número, pero además 0 es false, no pensé tener problemas.
resulta que el código acepta e ingresa a la estructura del IF

la solución es

```
  $data="Hola Mundo";
    if($data === 0){
      echo "Válido";
    }
```

Solo quisiera saber si me podrian explicar por que esto es válido.

Comment: Comentario que no vale como respuesta: Porque PHP es horrendo. ;)

Comment: jajajajajaj vale.

Comment: Mi versión de Php es 7.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La explicación ya la tienes, sin embargo me gustaría proponerte lo siguiente:

Podemos usar la función [strval](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strval.php) de PHP con la cual estariamos tratando de obtener: *el valor de string de una cadena*.

Por lo que si evaluamos:

```
if(strval(0) === "string") {
    echo "Es una cadena";
} else {
    echo "No es una cadena";
}
```

Nos dará:

> No es una cadena

De ahí podemos partir entonces para construir la sentencia de esta forma:

```
$uno = "algo";

echo ($uno == strval(0)) ? "Iguales" : "No iguales";
```

Que nos daría esta salida:

> No iguales

Considera [leer este enlace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Comment: Te agradezco  la documentación, revisare esto, me genero inquietud.

Answer (score 2):

Es algo natural de php, resulta que es la manera en la cual se interpreta la condición. Si deseas comparar de forma correcta un string puedes utilizar **"==="** (para una comparación estricta).

> Al utilizar **"=="** php parsea el sting a int, en este caso por defecto 0, por lo tanto se cumple la condición.

Comment: Lo he probado en la versión 7.3.8 y al utilizar "===" no ingresa al la estructura condicional